# Correct way to handle custom ColumnInterpreter in hbase

Tags: hbase, aggregation

I have a Class extending ColumnInterpreter, that is meant to handle BigDecimal instead of Long, which hbase provides out of the box.

Now I was thinking, that this was purely client functionality, so I figured, that all, I'd have to do is instantiate a new ColumnInterpreter as

```
final ColumnInterpreter<Long, Long> ci = new BigDecimalColumnInterpreter();
```

I was thinking, that this would just work, as I didn't change the Aggregateprotocol, and that therefor I would not need to create a new Endpoint.

However what happens, when I call it as follows:

```
AggregationClient ag = new AggregationClient(config);
avg = ag.avg(Bytes.toBytes(tableName), ci, scan);
```

The following will happen:

> 12/09/05 13:58:52 WARN
>   client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Error executing
>   for row  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after
>   attempts=10, exceptions: Wed Sep 05 13:58:12 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:14 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:15 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:16 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:18 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:20 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:24 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:28 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:36 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:52 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields
>
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.processExecs(HConnectionManager.java:1434)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorExec(HTable.java:1263)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.coprocessorExec(HTable.java:1243)
>     at
>   helpers.HbaseReaderBigDecimal.getWeekAvgSCAN(HbaseReaderBigDecimal.java:309)
>     at helpers.HbaseReaderBigDecimal.main(HbaseReaderBigDecimal.java:75)
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException:
>   Failed after attempts=10, exceptions: Wed Sep 05 13:58:12 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:14 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:15 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:16 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:18 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:20 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:24 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:28 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:36 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:52 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields
>
> at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ServerCallable.withRetries(ServerCallable.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker.invoke(ExecRPCInvoker.java:79)
>     at $Proxy7.getAvg(Unknown Source)   at
>   helpers.HbaseReaderBigDecimal$1.call(HbaseReaderBigDecimal.java:313)
>     at helpers.HbaseReaderBigDecimal$1.call(HbaseReaderBigDecimal.java:1)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$4.call(HConnectionManager.java:1422)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after
>   attempts=10, exceptions: Wed Sep 05 13:58:12 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:14 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:15 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:16 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:18 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:20 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:24 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:28 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:36 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields Wed Sep 05 13:58:52 CEST 2012,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.ExecRPCInvoker$1@14004204,
>   java.io.IOException: IPC server unable to read call parameters: Error
>   in readFields

My config is as follows:

```
config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
config.set(zookeeper, ip);
config.setLong("hbase.client.scanner.caching", 1000);
config.set("hbase.coprocessor.region.classes", "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.AggregateImplementation");
```

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should deploy the jar file containing your own ColumnInterpreter on the server side. The built-in EndPoint of HBase on the server cannot find your ColumnInterpreter.

Comment: "This ColumnInterpreter is required at the server side. You need to put the jar into the classpath of regionservers. HBase picks up all the jar under $hbase_home/lib folder. So you can put the jar containing the BDCI class in this folder. Please make sure that in your client side you are referencing the correct BDCI class(the full name of class at server side should match with the ColumnInterpreter class you reference on client side). Once you put the jar into lib folder then you will need to restart the cluster once so that the regionserver will the load the jar containing BDCI."